# Inverse of function - Difficulty solving

Tags: functions, inverse

$$y=\sqrt{35\tan (\frac{\pi }{180}x)}$$

I have a really hard time finding the inverse of this particular function. Can anyone shine some light on why that may be, or alternatively solve it if I'm just being silly? :-)

Thank you.

Comment: The simple trick of replacing $f(x)$ by $x$ and $x$ by $f(x)$ is not working?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be. :/

Comment: Can you show what you have done till now?

Comment: I'd be inserting f(x) instead of x seems to produce this. http://i.imgur.com/4prmga8.png

Comment: $y^2=35\tan (\frac{\pi x}{180})\Rightarrow \tan(\frac{\pi x}{180})=\frac{y^2}{(35)^2}...$

Comment: I don't know why you are going into graphs. Follow Razieh's steps. Take inverse of $tan$ on both sides.

Comment: Razieh fixed it to the wrong function. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^2=35\tan (\frac{\pi x}{180})\Rightarrow \tan(\frac{\pi x}{180})=\frac{y^2}{35}\Rightarrow \tan^{-1}(\frac{y^2}{35} )=\frac{\pi x}{180}\Rightarrow x= \frac{180}{\pi }\tan^{-1}(\frac{y^2}{35} )$$ Thus $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{180}{\pi }\tan^{-1}(\frac{x^2}{35} )$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your function is composed by performing the following operations on a give value of $x$:

- multiply by $\frac{\pi}{180}$
- apply the tangent function
- multiply by 35
- apply the square root function

This yields a value $f(x)$. So, starting with a given value of $f(x)$, you need to find operations that will undo each of these operations, in reverse order.

The individual operations listed are simple enough that you should know how to undo each one separately. Then just put them together. The result is the inverse function.

(Note: I have omitted any discussion of domain and range, but you should probably determine those as well.)

Comment: I have no experience inversing. What's the inverse of tan?

Comment: nice approach. +1

Comment: The inverse of $\tan$ is $\arctan$. For example, $\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$, so $\arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$ (note that for trig functions and inverse trig functions, the parentheses following the function name are traditionally omitted where the meaning is clear). Also, "$\arctan$" is sometimes written "$\tan^{-1}$" by convention, though that's not really an exponent, just traditional notation. Confusing if you haven't seen it.

Comment: Thanks, @abel . Just trying to teach a man to fish. :)

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 35
Square it
Take the ArcTan
Multiply by $\frac{180}{\pi}$

Comment: This is neither correct nor in proper MathJax formatting...please consider revising your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sqrt{35\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\sqrt{35}\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{35}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)}\right)^2=\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{35}}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)=\frac{y^2}{35}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\pi x}{180}=\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{35}\right)+\pi n\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{35}\right)+\pi n}{\frac{\pi}{180}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{180\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{35}\right)}{\pi}+180n$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$